# reading csv files with pandas fills dataframe with NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv output file from a datalogger that I want to bring into Python.
[image: temp_table]

Here is some of the data in csv:

```
"Name:,Data Instr INSTR 3/5/2020 11:51:59"
"Owner:,lab1"
"Comments:,"
"Acquisition Date:,3/5/2020 11:51:59 AM"
"&Instrument:,34970A,Address:,ASRL11::INSTR,Modules:,1,Slot3:,34901A"
"Total Channels:,4"
"Channel,Name,Function,Range,Resolution,AdvSettings,Scale,Gain,Offset,Label,Test,Low,High,HWAlarm"
"316,PCB_CTR,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,False,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1"
"317,Q24,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,False,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1"
"318,Q25,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,False,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1"
"319,Q18,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,False,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1"
"Scan  Control:,Start Action:,Immediately,Stop Action:,User Terminated"
"Scan,Time,316 <PCB_CTR> (C),Alarm 316,317 <Q24> (C),Alarm 317,318 <Q25> (C),Alarm 318,319 <Q18> (C),Alarm 319"
"1,3/5/2020 11:51:59:168,30.471,0,29.241,0,29.165,0,33.302,0"
"2,3/5/2020 11:52:01:152,32.197,0,30.634,0,30.564,0,34.819,0"
"3,3/5/2020 11:52:03:152,33.795,0,32.019,0,31.879,0,36.848,0"
```

I'm trying to use pandas to do it.  when I try reading it into python using

```
x[i]=pd.read_csv(file_name,usecols=[2,4,6,8],skiprows= 13,encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

I get:

```
print(x[i])
     Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 8
0           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
4           NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
..          ...         ...         ...         ...
518         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
519         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Thank you.

**EDIT**
The NaNs were due to the csv files actually being saved as unicode text out of Excel.  I thought I had saved them as CSV correctly, but maybe I missed it. After saving the files as CSVs (again, ;-)), now that I got rid of the NaNs. However, everything now imports as a single column, even when I explicitly add "delimiter =',' " to the pd.read_csv statement:

```
    x[i]=pd.read_csv(path+filename[i], delimiter= ',', skiprows=12)
print(x[i])
    Scan,Time,316 <PCB_CTR> (C),Alarm 316,317 <Q24> (C),Alarm 317,318 <Q25> (C),Alarm 318,319 <Q18> (C),Alarm 319
0    1,3/5/2020 10:03:21:164,46.334,0,43.755,0,45.7...                                                           
1    2,3/5/2020 10:03:22:149,46.997,0,44.262,0,46.3...                                                           
2    3,3/5/2020 10:03:23:149,47.615,0,44.671,0,46.9...                                                           
3    4,3/5/2020 10:03:24:149,48.267,0,45.229,0,47.6...                                                           
4    5,3/5/2020 10:03:25:149,48.861,0,45.711,0,48.1...                                                           
..                                                 ...                                                           
922  923,3/5/2020 10:18:43:149,97.59,0,88.915,0,91....                                                           
923  924,3/5/2020 10:18:44:149,96.879,0,88.514,0,91...                                                           
924  925,3/5/2020 10:18:45:149,96.027,0,87.984,0,90...                                                           
925  926,3/5/2020 10:18:46:149,95.168,0,87.333,0,89...                                                           
926  927,3/5/2020 10:18:47:149,94.385,0,86.8,0,89.1...                                                           
[927 rows x 1 columns]
```

**EDIT 2**
So, the reason why it is all importing as 1 column is because the csv file looks like this:

```
"Name:,Data Instr INSTR 3/5/2020 10:03:21"
"Owner:,lab1"
"Comments:,"
"Acquisition Date:,3/5/2020 10:03:21 AM"
"&Instrument:,34970A,Address:,ASRL11::INSTR,Modules:,1,Slot3:,34901A"
"Total Channels:,4"
"Channel,Name,Function,Range,Resolution,AdvSettings,Scale,Gain,Offset,Label,Test,Low,High,HWAlarm"
"316,PCB_CTR,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,False,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1"
"317,Q24,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,False,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1"
"318,Q25,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,False,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1"
"319,Q18,Temp (Type K),None,C,Temp (Type K)#1#0.016#Auto#0.001#C#Internal#0#false,False,1,0,C,High Only,0,105,Alarm 1"
"Scan  Control:,Start Action:,Immediately,Stop Action:,User Terminated"
"Scan,Time,316 <PCB_CTR> (C),Alarm 316,317 <Q24> (C),Alarm 317,318 <Q25> (C),Alarm 318,319 <Q18> (C),Alarm 319"
"1,3/5/2020 10:03:21:164,46.334,0,43.755,0,45.706,0,49.129,0"
"2,3/5/2020 10:03:22:149,46.997,0,44.262,0,46.35,0,49.773,0"
"3,3/5/2020 10:03:23:149,47.615,0,44.671,0,46.974,0,50.402,0"
"4,3/5/2020 10:03:24:149,48.267,0,45.229,0,47.628,0,50.879,0"
"5,3/5/2020 10:03:25:149,48.861,0,45.711,0,48.164,0,51.495,0"
"6,3/5/2020 10:03:26:149,49.455,0,46.323,0,48.783,0,51.9,0"
"7,3/5/2020 10:03:27:149,50.014,0,46.796,0,49.351,0,52.334,0"
"8,3/5/2020 10:03:28:149,50.586,0,47.237,0,49.845,0,52.959,0"
```

where every row is in quotes.  I didn't notice it initially when I first posted the question above....

I'm not sure why the quotes were there in the first place, and I'm not sure why Pandas cares anyway, if it is to use comma as a delimiter.  Note that the quotes won't show up in Excel --you'd need to open the file in Notepad to see these.

Once I removed the quotes, all is good.  Still, I don't understand why even if pandas interprets the row as a string, it doesn't separate the items based on the comma delimiter....

Answer (score 0):

```
Pet_Data= pd.read_csv('D:/data.csv',skiprows=14)

Pet_Data=Pet_Data.iloc[:,[2,4,6,8]]
```

Comment: Thank you.  Does your data have non_numerical data before row 15 like mine?  Why do i get the NaNs, if im skipping all the rows that do not include only numbers?
Why doesn’t ‘usecols’ in in the pd.read_csv  statement work?

Comment: It doesnt matter if its numerical or not, my test data is simillar , have you used my code ? Open your file in notepad and check what your separator is, maybe you can try to save this file in utf-8 formating

Comment: I tried it and get the same error......I'm not sure what I may be doing wrong. I'm editing the post to see if I can include the data and the instructions I"m trying ...

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I stiil get NaNs, For some reason that I can't explain with 100% certainty, it is not complaining about the  'usecols' (I think I may have had a filename issue ), so the usecols is now working, but it is still not importing the data correctly.

Comment: Why you are using x[i] as name of dataframe, just use normal var name as i do

Comment: I'm looping through a directory, and am trying to create arrays of matrices... X[1] = data from device 1, file_name[1], x[2] from device  2, etc....for this example, I do not show the arry of file_names, just 1 single filename.

Comment: OK--found out the Excel .csv were actually being saved as unicode text, not sure why.  I fixed that which got rid of the NaNs,  but now it reads all the data as 1 column. even when I explicitly add "delimiter=','".